# How to merge sdb to sda disk volumes using LVM for Debian server?

Tags: debian, filesystems, lvm

I got a Debian 10 server for web hosting which has two 1 TB disks, but the two disks are separated. I've been trying to figure out how to merge them but I always run into roadblocks, such as packages that don't exist with other answers and having some questions that are specific to other volumes. Any idea how how can make this a 2TB LVM?

```
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 894.3G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                  8:5    0 893.8G  0 part 
  ├─server--vg-root   254:0    0 892.8G  0 lvm  /
  └─server--vg-swap_1 254:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                     8:16   0 894.3G  0 disk
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a partition on `sdb` (optional you can use the entire disk) with `fdisk` or `parted`.
2. Create physical volume on the partition: `pvcreate /dev/sdb1`.
3. Add the new PV to you existing VG: `vgextend server-vg /dev/sdb1`.
4. If you are doing this to resize your root LV, you can do that by `lvresize --resizefs -L+800G server-vg/root`. (`-L+800G` means to grow it by 800 GiB, you can also use `-L+100%FREE` to use all free space)

Comment: Thanks, but the fourth command, `lvresize --resizefs -L+800G server-vg/root`  shows me a list of file volumes in vim, I can only quit and nothing else. Is that supposed to happen? When I exit it doesn't do anything

Comment: what is a "file volume"? No ,that's not supposed to happen, and I can't reproduce it. Are you sure you copy and pasted the `lvresize` command line correctly? if so, what does `lvs` show?